# Should I use reduce for mapping?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Just wondering should I stick with reduce for mapping?

The code is quite long. Is there a way to refactor this to look a bit cleaner?

```js
const items = [
 { Name: "one" },
 { error: true, code: "INVALID 1" },
 { Name: "two" },
 { Name: "three" },
 { error: true, code: "INVALID OTHER" },
]

const filtered = items.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (item.error === true) {
    if (!acc.errors) {
      acc.errors = [];
    }

    acc.errors.push(item);

    return acc;
  }

  if (!acc.items) {
    acc.items = [];
  }

  acc.items.push(item);

  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: So, you want to take your array and split it into two - errors and items?

Comment: @VLAZ yes that correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the only difference between the two parts of the reducer is the key you push to, extract the `key` selection, and make everything dependant on the `key`:

```js
const items = [{"Name":"one"},{"error":true,"code":"INVALID 1"},{"Name":"two"},{"Name":"three"},{"error":true,"code":"INVALID OTHER"}]

const filtered = items.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const key = item.error ? 'errors' : 'items'
  
  if (!acc[key]) acc[key] = []

  acc[key].push(item)

  return acc
}, {})

console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: Also possible to simplify further - you *know* you only have two possible keys, so pass the initial argument as `{errors: [], items: []}`, so you don't need to run the `if` on every iteration.

Answer (score 3):

Is the only determinate of which object it falls under just whether or not the object contains an `error` key? If so, what about something like this:

```js
const items = [
    { Name: "one" },
    { error: true, code: "INVALID 1" },
    { Name: "two" },
    { Name: "three" },
    { error: true, code: "INVALID OTHER" },
];

const filtered = {
    errors: items.filter(i => Object.keys(i).includes('error')),
    items: items.filter(i => !Object.keys(i).includes('error'))
}

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: If you have (almost) the *same* predicate twice, you can extract it into `predicate = i => Object.keys(i).includes('error')` and then use a `not = fn => (...args) => !fn(...args)` to flip the result, so you can call `items.filter(predicate)` and `items.filter(not(predicate))`

Comment: @VLAZ That's a good point -- I was trying to keep the predicate logic inline to keep it to as few lines of code as possible (although you could definitely argue that the redundancy I've introduced is less pretty)

Comment: To simplify it further replace the keys().includes with `'error' in i`.

Comment: @OriDrori also an argument for extracting it. You don't need to change the logic twice for this.